# Is there a subsitute for subequations?

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

Is there substitute for the `subequations` environment?  For instance, we can use `align` instead of the `equations` environment.  What is the complement of `subequations` that would yield the same numbering convention?

I looked through post on `subequations` trying to see if there was a suggestion about a possible different environment, but I didn't find anything which doesn't mean it doesn't exist; I just couldn't find it.

**Edit:**

To avoid confusion, I am aware of nesting `align` inside `subequations`.  However, I am trying to avoid the `subequations` environment all together.  This is because I am trying to trouble shoot something and `align` plays nicer with `hyperref` compared to `equations`.  Therefore, I want to isolate out the use of `subequations` (maybe this environment plays nice with `hyperref`  but I need to test something).

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your question. You can use `\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
y & = d\y & = cx+d\y & = bx^{2}+cx+d\y & = ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d
\end{align}
\end{subequations}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I updated my post to reflect this information so as to avoid confusion (I hope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you test the dgroup environment from the breqn package?

Below you will find a mwe.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
With amsmath:
\begin{subequations}
  \begin{equation}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
  \end{equation}
  \begin{equation}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
  \end{equation}
\end{subequations}

With breqn:
\begin{dgroup}
  \begin{dmath}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
  \end{dmath}
  \begin{dmath}
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2
  \end{dmath}
\end{dgroup}
\end{document}
```

And below you will find a ilustration of the pdf generate from the code above (sorry for the bad quality, is the first time that I post a picture).

[image: Ilustration of the pdf generate from the code above]

Comment: So `dgroup` is based off of `align`?

Comment: The breqn package implement breaking line and align for long equations. You must use `dmath` for every equation (a equation like `f(x, y) = x^2 + 2 x y + y^2 = (x + y)^2`) and tho group equations together you must use `dgroup`. You can't use `align` with `dgroup`. For more information you can look at breqn's manual.